# Access the Add-on SDK from within a traditional XUL-based add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I have a large and complex XUL-based addon for which I need to use a few functions from the Add-on SDK. Is this possible? If so, does anyone have working sample code, preferably using the page-worker module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is the way devtools does it, but certain modules will choke (the obvious candidate being `self`). I think you will have better luck with low-level modules.

```js
let {Loader} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", {});
let loader = new Loader.Loader({
  paths: {
    "": "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/"
  },
  globals: {},
});

let require = Loader.Require(loader, { id: "myaddon" })
// now you can require addon-sdk modules
```

Comment: The documentation is here, FYI: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/toolkit/loader.html

Comment: When I run this with the page-worker module, I get "TypeError: rootURI is undefined".